# Standard name for a function that modifies a function to ignore an argument

Tags: functional-programming

I'm using Python because it's generally easy to read, but this is not a Python-specific question.

Take the following Python function `strip_argument`:

```
def strip_argument(func_with_no_args):
  return lambda unused: func_with_no_args()
```

In use, I can pass a no-argument function to `strip_argument`, and it will return a function that accepts one argument that is never used. For example:

```
# some API I want to use
def set_click_event_listener(listener):
  """Args:
      listener: function which will be passed the view that was clicked.
  """
  # ...implementation...

# my code
def my_click_listener():
  # I don't care about the view, so I don't want to make that an arg.
  print "some view was clicked"

set_click_event_listener(strip_argument(my_click_listener))
```

Is there a standard name for the function `strip_argument`? I'm interested in any languages that have a function like this in the standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most functional programming languages offer a `const` function, that's a function that will always ignore it's first parameter and return it's second. If you pass a function to const that's exactly the behavior you described.

In Haskell you can use it like that:

```
f x = x + 1
g = const f
g 2 3 == 4 --2 is ignored and 3 is incremented
```

I have done a quick search for such a function in python but haven't found anything. It seems the standard is to use a lambda function as you did.